# Display a table from Excel as html table - c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, import, excel-2007

I have an Excel file with a formatted table. Right now I have a database in sql server, I'm pulling the data into my c# asp.net program. I want to know if anyone has an idea of what I should try to use that Excel format to display data from a query at a webpage without having to go in and construct the table from scratch. I tried looking for a good tutorial on how to import an excel file and use it as a template for crystal reports, had no luck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I have used a third party component called ASPOSE.NET to acheive this. ASPOSE provides extensive formatting options and support a wide variety of file formats.

However it is not a free product.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. Just as a note, I ended up rendering a table programatically looping through my data (I was using a stored procedure to pull different dollar amounts by month). For the fields that required a string constant I did:  `TableRow Header1 = new TableRow();
            TableCell Label1 = new TableCell();
            Label1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("More TEXT"));
            Label1.ColumnSpan = 4;
            Label1.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
            Header1.Cells.Add(Label1);
            TABLE.Rows.Add(Header1); `